# Hide file extensions except for executables

Tags: malware, windows

Is there a way (preferably ***without*** editing the registry) to hide file extensions except for executables? (I want to see `a.exe` as `a.exe`, but `a.docx` as `a`.)

The idea is that any file I have associated with an installed application is relatively safe. An exe, on the other hand, is more likely to do harm.

Comment: Are you sure it's a reasonable assumption that any file associated with an installed app is harmless? Think about `.pdf`, `.swf`, `.doc`, etc. which are often used to deliver malware. And what about executable scripts (`.bat`, `.cmd`, ...)?

Comment: @Arminius Thanks. You are absolutely correct. But that's exactly why I wrote `relatively safe` and `executables`, and only used `exe` later as an example.

Comment: @Arminius No problem. Perhaps you're right, but I assumed this would be something users here have dealt with before. If I see there are no answers in some time I might move it to SU.

Comment: @Arminius You can vote to migrate questions to Superuser.com, by the way.

Comment: afaik, from 25 years of windows, it's all or nothing in terms of visible extensions.

Comment: **(preferably without editing the registry)** is not possible at all, because changing each of explorer settings translates to a corresponding change in registry. It's technically possible, but explorer doesn't support selective omission of extensions.

Answer (score -1):

I hope you are knowing, Here is not any method to something like this, if you want to hide extension then all extension will be hide or all extension will be shown. for this follow steps is below mentioned.

```
open control panel >> File Explorer Options >> Locate "View" tab >> Hidden Files and folder >> Don't show hidden files, folders, or drives or Show Hidden Files, Folders, and Drives. select one from what  you want.
```

as you mentioned in question for custom extension I Don't know, if you found solutions please post on same.